# How to solve the problem with google drive api?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I have created tools for the video editor so that the video editor receives edits from customers to the video (analog frame.io, filestage, zipflow, etc.).

I'm having a problem with accessing videos via the API on my website. Я The functionality of my tool is as follows:

1. I upload videos (various lengths) to my google drive
2. I provide access to the video "For anyone with a link."
3. Copy the link to the video
4. I insert a link to a video from Google Drive into my website.
   VERY IMPORTANT!!! The video is uploaded to the site from google drive via the google drive API.
5. I can watch the video already on my site. BUT!!! Video even less than 1 minute long stops loading, and I get the error "Failed to load video ..."
6. I turn on VPN, and the error disappears, and you can watch the video.

I'm not very technical, but the programmer who's helping me suggested that Google thinks I'm a bot and is blocking me because I only watch the video, not download it. However, I believe this may not be the case.

How can I fix this error and watch videos on my site without having to use a VPN?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Verify API Quotas: Make sure you are not exceeding any API usage quotas set by Google Drive API. Check your API dashboard to monitor your usage and ensure you have not hit any limits.

Implement API Key: If you haven't already, create an API key and set up proper API restrictions in the Google Cloud Console. Ensure that the API key is used in your website's code to authenticate requests to the Google Drive API.

Use OAuth 2.0 Authentication: Instead of using a public link accessible to anyone ("For anyone with a link"), implement OAuth 2.0 authentication to access the videos. This will provide better control over access and may reduce the chances of Google flagging your requests as suspicious.

Throttle Requests: If your application makes too many requests to the Google Drive API in a short period, it might be considered suspicious behavior. Implement request throttling to limit the number of API requests per second/minute to a reasonable rate.

Implement Error Handling: Handle API errors appropriately in your website's code. If there are errors returned by the Google Drive API, make sure to display helpful error messages to users instead of generic error messages.

Check User-Agent Header: Some applications might get blocked if the User-Agent header in the API requests is missing or incorrect. Make sure your requests include an appropriate User-Agent header.

Verify Video Format: Ensure that the video format you are trying to play on your website is supported by the browsers. Different browsers have different video format support, and using a format that is not supported might lead to loading issues.

Optimize Video Delivery: Consider using video streaming techniques like adaptive bitrate streaming (ABR) or progressive streaming to improve video loading and playback performance.

Test on Different Networks: Test your website and video loading on various networks to ensure that the issue is not specific to your network connection or IP address range.

Reach out to Google Support: If you have tried the above steps and are still facing issues, reach out to Google Drive API support to seek assistance with the specific problem you are encountering.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This answer appears likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). A heads-up that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. Thanks!

**Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.